# FadeIn Mouseover Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know you can `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` on mouseover but I was just wondering how to do it when you add the background image to the css:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
     $('.bubble').mouseover(function() {             
         $('.bubbleSpeach').fadeIn("slow");          
         var path= this.id + ".png";                 
         $('.bubbleSpeach').css({'background-image': "url(" + path + ")"});              
    });
```

This is what I use at the moment. But the fadeIn doesn't work.

Ideally, the image background would change but with a fade in transition and a fadeout when the mouse is not hover anymore.

Comment: Set your background image to `opacity: 0` and then animate it to `opacity: 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$('.bubble').on({
       mouseover:function() {                       
           var path= this.id + ".png";                 
           $('.bubbleSpeach').css({'background-image': "url(" + path + ")"}).fadeIn("slow");
       },
       mouseout: function(){
           $('.bubbleSpeach').fadeOut("slow");
       }
});
```

Try `adding css` first `then fade it in`.

Comment: Also, the Jquery actions were queing one after the other one so I had to use the Stop() method before fadeout and fadein. Like this : stop().fadeIn() .

Comment: I don't think this could cause something like animate but you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would to be use [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$("#id").hover(function(){
    $("#exampleText").fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#exampleText").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".bubble",function() {    
//your code..for fadeIn
 });
```

try like this..

Answer (score 0):

What object does bubble represent? The div or is this the whole page?

Have you tried the hover() function?

Answer (score 0):

this might what u want it uses animate effect with opacity

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('bubbleSpeach').css({'background':'url/img.png'})      
 $('.bubble').mouseover(function() {             
    $('.bubbleSpeach').animate({opacity:0)},1000 function() {
        $('bubbleSpeach').css({'background':'url/img2.png'})
        $('.bubbleSpeach').animate({opacity:1}),1000}
   }); 
});
```